# How to randomize questions every time the user play

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a quiz game that will display the score of the user in the activity at the end of the same. I have 50 questions, but only 10 questions will display everytime the user plays. I am having trouble because a cannot save the score of the user.

The following is my *java* code, assuming `Q1.java` and `Q2.java` are my *java* class. `Whoami.java` is the code where the users starts de quiz, and `score.java` where the score is displayed. Please help me guys! Thanks in advance!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question1);

    TextView q1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q1);
    q1.setText("I am an amphibian who has undergone metamorphosis. I have slippery skin, and spend most of my time in or near water. I breathe with lungs now, but when I was a tadpole I had gills.");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int cnt = 0;

    final Animation animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.anim_scale);
    final Animation animAlpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.anim_alphas);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnopt1_a);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnopt1_b);
    Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnopt1_c);

    ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ImageView img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    ImageView img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    img1.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                arg0.startAnimation(animScale);
            }});

    img2.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                arg0.startAnimation(animAlpha);
            }});

    img3.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                arg0.startAnimation(animAlpha);
            }});

    if(btn1.isClickable())      
    {
        img1.startAnimation(animScale);
        cnt++;  
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Q2.class);
        i.putExtra("score",cnt);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    else if (btn2.isClickable())
    {
        img2.startAnimation(animAlpha);
    }

    else if (btn3.isClickable())
    {
        img3.startAnimation(animAlpha);
    }
}
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

then this is my other class name Q2.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_question2);

    TextView q2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.q2);
    q2.setText("I am a bird that has wings, but does not fly. I spend most of my time in the water. I am known to live in colder regions like Antarctica.");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int cnt = 0;

    final Animation animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.anim_scale);
    final Animation animAlpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.anim_alphas);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnopt2_a);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnopt2_b);
    Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnopt2_c);

    ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    ImageView img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    ImageView img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

    img1.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                arg0.startAnimation(animScale);
            }});

    img2.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                arg0.startAnimation(animAlpha);
            }});

    img3.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                arg0.startAnimation(animAlpha);
            }});

    if(btn1.isClickable())      
    {
        img1.startAnimation(animScale);
        cnt++;  
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Q3.class);
        i.putExtra("score",cnt);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    else if (btn2.isClickable())
    {
        img2.startAnimation(animAlpha);
    }

    else if (btn3.isClickable())
    {
        img3.startAnimation(animAlpha);
    }
}
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

here is my Score.java

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
     try
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int score = intent.getIntExtra("score",0);

        Button btnok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnok);
        btnok.setOnClickListener(this);

        TextView txtscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtscore);
        txtscore.setText("Your score is : " + score +"/10");
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         try {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
 }

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0.getId()) 
    {

case R.id.btnok:
     Intent i = new Intent (this,MainMenu.class);
     startActivity(i);       
default:
     break;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

}

and lastly my Whoami.java class

```
public class Whoami extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_whoami);


 Button bplay =(Button) findViewById(R.id.bplay);
 bplay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Random random = new Random(); 

        switch(random.nextInt(50)) 
        { 

           case 0:
            Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q1.class);     
            startActivity (newActivity1);
           break;
           case 1:
            Intent newActivity2 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q2.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity2);
           break;
           case 2:
            Intent newActivity3 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q3.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity3);
           break;
           case 3:
            Intent newActivity4 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q4.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity4);
           break;
           case 4:
            Intent newActivity5 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q5.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity5);
            break;
           case 5:
            Intent newActivity6 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q6.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity6);
            break;
           case 6:
            Intent newActivity7 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q7.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity7);
            break;
           case 7:
            Intent newActivity8 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q8.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity8);
            break;
           case 8:
            Intent newActivity9 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q9.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity9);
            break;
           case 9:
            Intent newActivity10 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q10.class);     
            startActivity(newActivity10);
            break;
           case 10:
             Intent newActivity11 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q11.class);     
             startActivity(newActivity11);
             break;
           case 11:
             Intent newActivity12 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q12.class);     
             startActivity(newActivity12);
             break;
           case 12:
             Intent newActivity13 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q13.class);     
             startActivity(newActivity13);
             break;
           case 13:
               Intent newActivity14 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q14.class);
               startActivity(newActivity14);
               break;
           case 14:
               Intent newActivity15 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q15.class);
               startActivity(newActivity15);
               break;
           case 15:
               Intent newActivity16 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q16.class);
               startActivity(newActivity16);
               break;
           case 16:
               Intent newActivity17 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q17.class);     
               startActivity (newActivity17);
               break;
           case 17:
               Intent newActivity18 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q18.class);     
               startActivity(newActivity18);
               break;
           case 18:
               Intent newActivity19 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q19.class);     
               startActivity(newActivity19);
               break;
           case 19:
               Intent newActivity20 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q20.class);     
               startActivity(newActivity20);
               break;
           case 20:
               Intent newActivity21 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q21.class);     
               startActivity(newActivity21);
               break;
           case 21:
               Intent newActivity22 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q22.class);     
               startActivity(newActivity22);
               break;
           case 22:
               Intent newActivity23 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q23.class);     
               startActivity(newActivity23);
               break;
           case 23:
               Intent newActivity24 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q24.class);     
               startActivity(newActivity24);
               break;
           case 24:
               Intent newActivity25 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q25.class);     
               startActivity(newActivity25);
               break;
           case 25:
               Intent newActivity26 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q26.class);     
               startActivity(newActivity26);
               break;
           case 26:
                Intent newActivity27 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q27.class);     
                startActivity(newActivity27);
                break;
           case 27:
                Intent newActivity28 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q28.class);     
                startActivity(newActivity28);
                break;
           case 28:
                Intent newActivity29 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q29.class);     
                startActivity(newActivity29);
                break;
           case 29:
                  Intent newActivity30 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q30.class);
                  startActivity(newActivity30);
                  break;
           case 30:
                  Intent newActivity31 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q31.class);
                  startActivity(newActivity31);
                  break;
           case 31:
                  Intent newActivity32 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q32.class);
                  startActivity(newActivity32);
                  break;
           case 32:
                  Intent newActivity33 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q33.class);     
                  startActivity(newActivity33);
                  break;
           case 33:
                  Intent newActivity34 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q34.class);     
                  startActivity(newActivity34);
                  break;
           case 34:
                  Intent newActivity35 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q35.class);     
                  startActivity(newActivity35);
                  break;
           case 35:
                  Intent newActivity36 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q36.class);     
                  startActivity(newActivity36);
                  break;
           case 36:
                  Intent newActivity37 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q37.class);     
                  startActivity(newActivity37);
                  break;
           case 37:
                  Intent newActivity38 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q38.class);     
                  startActivity(newActivity38);
                  break;
           case 38:
                  Intent newActivity39 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q39.class);     
                  startActivity(newActivity39);
                  break;
           case 39:
                  Intent newActivity40 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q40.class);     
                  startActivity(newActivity40);
                  break;
           case 40:
                  Intent newActivity41 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q41.class);     
                  startActivity(newActivity41);
                  break;
           case 41:
                   Intent newActivity42 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q42.class);     
                   startActivity(newActivity42);
                   break;
           case 42:
                   Intent newActivity43 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q43.class);     
                   startActivity(newActivity43);
                   break;
           case 43:
                   Intent newActivity44 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q44.class);     
                   startActivity(newActivity44);
                   break;
           case 44:
                   Intent newActivity45 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q45.class);
                   startActivity(newActivity45);
                   break;
           case 45:
                   Intent newActivity46 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q46.class);
                   startActivity(newActivity46);
                   break;
           case 46:
                   Intent newActivity47 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q47.class);
                   startActivity(newActivity47);
                   break;
           case 47:
                   Intent newActivity48 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q48.class);     
                   startActivity (newActivity48);
                   break;
           case 48:
                   Intent newActivity49 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q49.class);     
                   startActivity(newActivity49);
                   break;
           case 49:
                   Intent newActivity50 = new Intent(Whoami.this,Q50.class);     
                   startActivity(newActivity50);
                   break;

        }
    }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Your title asks how to randomize questions, in the text you write the problem is that you have trouble saving the users score. Please only ask one specific question (per question), as this site is not a _here is my code, please fix it_ place. We'll gladly help if you explain your problem and show us the _relevant_ part of your code.

Comment: why are you creating 1 activity for each question? try keeping one activity and just update the question on that activity.

Comment: What if you have 1000 questions? Will you write 1000-branch switch?

Comment: @Raj thanks to you..but how can i do that?can you give me example of that?

Answer (score 0):

create a QuestionActivity class and xml layout along with it.
pass question as string to the Activity through

```
intentInstance.putExtra("question", yourRandomQuestion);
```

and get the passed value from the QuestionActivity class using

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String question = intent.getStringExtra("question");
```

then place the question into a TextView.

hope it helps:)

Comment: what did you mean?i will put my question here inside this parenthesis?("question")

Comment: just have all your set questions in strings.xml, just call any question with its name:)